# Consulta tablas prestashop MYSQL

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Buenos dias,

Mi pregunta es que en nuestra web en prestashop hay dos filas newsletter y optin que selecciona los clientes.

Me gustaria cambiar por base de datos que los clientes que tengan seleccionado optin los puedas pasar a newsletter

La tabla es ps_custommer
Las filas newsletter y optin
Los valores son 0 y 1 ;

Gracias

Comment: Deberías poner la definición de las tablas, sería mas fácil ayudarte sin tener que instalar un prestashop

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE ps_customers SET newsletter = 1 WHERE optin = 1.
```

La tabla por defecto es customers con una 'M', tu lo has puesto con 2. Tenlo en cuenta...

Comment: eso es, que sencillo y me he comido la cabeza... gracias